# Streaming Qt over ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg, qt

I am trying to stream a program over `ssh` and it doesn't work. It is written in qml and I've already compiled it, but `qmlscene` doesn't work either (doesn't matter what file). The error I'm getting is

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can someone help me? I am trying to use `ssh`, because `xcb` doesn't work on the Pi, only `eglfs`, but that is not what I am looking for and comes with some caveats.

Comment: You're trying to stream *from* the pi or *to* the pi?  And display it where?

Comment: @goldilocks From the pi and display it on my computer

Comment: Okay, I'm going to migrate this -- it seems like a general linux question.

Comment: Stupid question, are you using `ssh -X user@pi`?

Comment: @SailorCire Yes, I am. Your assumption is brilliant btw

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible since QML requires GLX or EGL.

Comment: @NathanOsman I have that on my computer, obviously

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it works over SSH.

Comment: @NathanOsman I think it's actually a problem with the Pi. AFAIK the mesa driver is crap, so I should probably try glxinfo over ssh and test for direct rendering.